# javascript alternative to sed script

Tags: javascript, regex, text, sed

I have a sed script which will read in a file and, if a line begins with a space, remove the preceding line break and the matched whitespace so that that line and the preceding line are joined together.

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n / /;ta' -e 'P;D' input_file_name.txt
```

Is there any way to have javascript do the same using regular expressions?

I am reading in the file using the HTML5 [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way is to read the whole file and then do a replace like:

```
content = content.replace(/\r?\n /g, ' ');
```

If the file fits in memory that is.