# javascript equivalent to sed

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to trim string, eg.

> Pencil (4,99 USD)

to just a bracket numeric value:

> 4,99

I now a bit about regular expressions in sed, so I'd do that like this: `sed "s#.*(##" | sed "s# USD.*##"`. But how should I use any regular expressions in javascript `replace` function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript alternative to sed script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818895/javascript-alternative-to-sed-script)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need for replace here. Using the `match` function is probably easier and more appropriate:

```
var priceStr;
var match = "Pencil (4,99 USD)".match(/[\d,]+/)
if(match)
    priceStr = match[0];
```

You could refine the regex a bit. This one will simply give you the first substring made up of digits and/or commas. But if your string is always this short and of this format, it should be alright. However, if the name can contain numbers or commas you should probably start with the parenthesis and use a capturing group instead:

```
var priceStr;
var match = "Pencil, black, thickness 2 (4,99 USD)".match(/\(([\d,]+)/)
if(match)
    priceStr = match[1];
```

A short explanation for the latter regex. `\(` is just a literal opening parenthesis. The unescaped parentheses "capture" what is matched inside, so that you can later retrieve the price without that literal opening parenthesis. `[\d,]` is a character class, which matches either a digit or a comma, and `+` simply repeats the 1 or more times. And then we can retrieve the full match out of `match[0]` and the (first) capturing group out of `match[1]`.

Comment: The code should be in a try-block though, since it throws if no match was found.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas good point, but I prefer to just check for the existence of the match (as I edited)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your answer! But please, give me a fishing rod instead of only fish :).
What does the `/\(([\d,]+)/` mean?

Comment: @gogowitczak there you go ;) ... sorry, I usually do this, but left it out due to the "I know a bit about regular expressions" ;)

Comment: @m.buettner thanks a lot for you efford! I have one more 'dumb' question: why is `priceStrNew = priceStrNew.replace(/[,]/, ".");`throwing an excepion. I'd like to replace comma wiith dot.

Comment: @gogowitczak did you mean `priceStrNew = priceStr.replace(/[,]/, ".");`?

Comment: No, but my problem was somwhere else. Now I've fixed that and I'm stuck with another trouble - how can I trim a string to only two digits after comma/dot? For example, I have "149.2999999" and I'd like to get "149.29" (not necessary mathematical round-up, just simple string trim)

Comment: @gogowitczak that is what I meant with "You could refine the regex a bit.". For instance, if you can be sure that there will **always** be a comma, you could use `/\((\d*,\d{0,2})/`

Comment: @m.buettner, hmm, it's not working. I've typed `var foo = "123.29999";` and `foo = foo.match(/\((\d*.\d{0,2})/);` - result is `foo` equal to `null` (in filezilla debugger).

Comment: @gogowitczak of course. there is no literal `(` in your input string anymore (but the regex tries to find one). also note that you need to escape the `.` like `\.` otherwise `.` is the regex wildcard that matches any non-linebreak character.

Comment: @m.buettner I's working now. For future visitors: `foo = foo.match(/\d*\.\d{0,2}/);`
I really don't know how to thank you - you've helped me so much!

Comment: @gogowitczak no worries, that's what this site is there for ;)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to do:

```
str.replace(/[^\d\.\,]/, "")
```

It means getting rid of everything that is not a digit, a comma, or a dot.

Comment: You should note that this gets problematic if the product's (?) name contains digits or decimal separators (just like my first code snippet does).

Answer (score 0):

One of several possibilities is:

```
var match = "Pencil (4,99 USD)".match(/[^(]+(?= USD)/);
```